# How to avoid a certain class hierarchy to execute

Tags: html, css, colors, html-table

I have my website has a div based structure with table inside for tabular data, The data for this table is being read from files and can not be changed.

```
.main-grid .grid-view .row-body td { 
    background-color: "#FFFFFF" 
}
```

The above works fine. Now I have a table that has `bgColor` defined in its `<tr>` tag but it does not reflects due to above `CSS` rule.

This `<td>` is at hierarchy `.main-grid .grid-view td`.  Below code come from file being read and I can not modify it or add class to it.

```
<tr bgColor="#eeffcc">
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Please advise. Changing class name is an option but i want to find out some generic solution. As such issue may come in other modules also.

to be more accurate; I have added this live above in the question. "Below code come from file being read and I can not modify it or add class to it."

Comment: in the css you are targeting a td in your html you are targeting an tablerow !

Comment: Please clarify: what is your question? What is the problem?

Comment: So, you *cannot* remove the inline `bgColor`? That's the real answer. (if the CSS wasn't selecting the wrong element...)

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "CSS |" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 0):

`bgColor` should not be used anymore. Use only `classes` to define the colours of your elements.

Comment: Actually this data is read from the file so i do not have any control over it. i create the divs and print the complete file contents in it. File contents include multiple paragraphs, divs and tables. This table has used bgColor.

Answer (score 0):

Guess you have misspelled the attributes name. Maybe you want:

```
<tr style="background:#eeffcc;">
  <td></td>
</tr>
```

Explicitly defined styles will always overwrite rules from css-files.

Comment: The attribute is spelled correctly, it just doesn't play well with CSS because it's not CSS :)

Answer (score 0):

Your inline code isn't valid use

```
<tr style="background:#eeffcc;">
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

To overwrite your css rules, you have to use the style attribute !

Answer (score 0):

1. try to avoid those deprecated attributes like `bgColor`
2. inline-styles have the highest priority, use them as follows: `style="background-color:#ccc;"`. They should be avoided though. Always try to use css-stylesheets.
3. In your example, the css-declaration targets the `td`-Element, your `bgColor`Attribute the `tr` Element and thus gets overridden.

Comment: Actually this data is read from the file so i do not have any control over it. i create the divs and print the complete file contents in it. File contents include multiple paragraphs, divs and tables and bgColor attribute is defined in it.

Comment: Well, what is your exact problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS is not valid; make the following correction

```
.main-grid .grid-view .row-body td { 
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

With no quotes **""** enclosing the color value.

Answer (score -3):

Usually inline css style hav higher prioruty, so you can try smth like this:

```
<tr style="bgColor:#eeffcc;">
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: that not a valid style-declaration